# Why is FormArray not assignable to NgIterable<any>?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I tried to pass a FormArray into a component.  This component template iterates over FormArray and displays data.  It allows the user to add to the array or remove items.

ChildComponent ts

```js
@Input()
public formArray!:FormArray;
```

Then in the template I try:

```html
<div class="formRow child2" *ngFor="let year of formArray; let i=index">
  List Number #{{i+1}} &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <mat-form-field class="col3 no-bottom" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>{{ "YEAR" | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Year" mask="0000" [formControl]="year">
  </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-flat-button color="accent" (click)="addYear()">
      <span class="material-icons">Add Year</button>
```

However, I get an error message:

```
Type 'FormArray' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'.
<div class="formRow child2" *ngFor="let year of formArray; let i=index">
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be

```
*ngFor="let year of formArray.controls;
```

formArray.controls is iterable

See working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyfuwp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I noticed in the child component you used 
`<div formArrayName="items"`
Items is a name from the parent component.  Does it need to be passed in? or can this be done with passing in the fewest amount of variables into the child component.

Comment: @user6269972 Yes, in this case, you will have to use 'items' in child component.